# How can I disable the pawn shop alarm in Fallout 3: DC Interiors Mod?

Tags: fallout-3, fallout-3-dc-interiors

I've been playing around with the DC Interiors Mod for Fallout 3, and it's generally great - except I can't figure out how to turn off the alarm in the Pawn Shop near Northwest Seneca Station.

I've combed the shop over, and even the 'second floor' accessible through the hotel next door, but I can't seem to find a switch.

According to [the mod creator](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/115343-dcinteriors-project/page-114), it **is** possible to disable it, indeed it's the only way to access most of the items in the shop. However, he doesn't like giving out the location in public.

Does anyone know how to disable the pawn shop alarm?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The trick is to search upstairs **next door** in the hotel. The wall has been blasted away, so you can get into the upstairs area of the pawn shop (where the collapsed staircase leads). The alarm will be going off up there as well.

There will be a work area with a workbench and a few knickknacks on shelves, an office with a few desks, and a kitchen/eating area.

If you still can't find it:

> Check in the office area. The switch under one of the desks.